# Cancel Transaction on Aurora Bridge

Tags: cryptography, token, transfer, bridge

Can I cancel a transaction on Aurora and Rainbow Bridge? The transaction requires too much gas. I am afraid I have lost my funds.

Answer (score 0):

Once confirmed on the blockchain, the transaction on Aurora’s trustless Rainbow Bridge cannot be cancelled.

If the fee is too high at the moment, you can wait for the ETH gas prices to go down and finalize the transaction at any time in future.